# getPointerPosition() of stage in React-Konva

Tags: reactjs, konvajs

I would like to get cursor position on Stage in React-Konva by getPointerPosition()
`handleStageOnMouseMove(e){
    console.log(e.getPointerPosition());
}

render(){
    return(
      {this.handleStageOnMouseOver(e)} }
      >
        Hello World
      
    );
}
`
But I found some trouble that is when I move cursor over  the program will return  's event instead of  's event.

** I have some method that is use 'ref' attribute to references  but I don't know how to get cursor position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleMouseMove = (e) => {
  // there are several ways to get stage reference

  // first is
  var stage = e.currentTarget;

  // or this:
  stage = this.stageRef.getStage();

  // or even this:
  stage = e.target.getStage();

  this.setState({
    cursor: stage.getPointerPosition()
  });
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/xp9o58nl2z

Comment: Is it possible that getPointerPosition() doesn't exits anymore

Comment: @IAMTHEBEST no, for `konva@4.x.x` there is `stage.getPointerPosition()`